# How to pass custom argument to linux timer's function?

Tags: c, pointers, linux-kernel

Upon some conditions, I want to schedule a timer (`struct timer_list`) that works on custom data. The `function` field of this structure holds the actual function that will be triggered, and is defined as below :

```c
void (*function)(unsigned long);
```

The thing is I want to pass a pointer instead of the `unsigned long`. I know that depending on the architecture, the int-ptr conversion may or may not be safe, but I could not find if all the architectures align `long` integers with pointers so here is my question (in fact, a two-in-one) :

Is it safe to perform a `long` to `void*` cast ? If no, how should I handle the `unsigned long` argument to get the data pointer I want in the timer function ?

Comment: I wouldn't do that. There must be a reason that the parameter is of type unsigned long. Is there a manpage avaliable for this?

Comment: @bash.d The only comment for this in the manpage of `add_timer` and friends is that the argument would be used to differentiate between timers that performs the same function. There's nothing else about it

Comment: Well, then try to go with Joachim's suggestion. I wouldn't cast at all!

Comment: @bash.d I was thinking about this kind of solution, I just wanted to be sure not to miss anything that would avoid me to using it, hence the question. Don't worry I will not cast ! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the passed number to be an index into an array that contains your custom data structure.

Comment: I infer from your answer that the only constraint on `long` is it must be at least 32-bit wide and that casting to pointer is not safe, am I right ?

Comment: @Rerito Correct, it's not safe to typecast to/from pointers, and the size could be different.

Comment: So it seems that the only solution would be to have some global variable storing the (long, data) couples. Like the array you suggested or any dynamic structures (I thought of using trees indexed by the `long` key). Anyway, answer accepted !

Answer (score 15):

Linux kernel 4.15 [removed the data field](https://lwn.net/Articles/735887/) entirely, rendering the answers here obsolete. From what I inferred, preferred way to pass arguments to timer callback is to enclose them in a struct together with a timer and use the `from_timer` macro to retrieve them, which is defined as

```
#define from_timer(var, callback_timer, timer_fieldname) \
    container_of(callback_timer, typeof(*var), timer_fieldname)
```

So in order to pass arguments, define an additional struct as

```
struct timer_data {
    struct timer_list timer;
    datatype data;
};
```

and pass it to setup function

```
struct timer_data *tmd = init_timer_data(); //your logic for init
timer_setup(&tmd->timer, callback, flags);
```

Later, use the `from_timer` to retrieve the arguments. By default, pointer to timer_list is passed to the callback function, instead of the `unsigned long data` in versions prior to 4.15.

```
void callback(struct timer_list *t) {
    struct timer_data *tmd = from_timer(tmd, t, timer);
    datatype data = tmd -> data;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In case of timer functions and in some other situations, it **is possible** to just cast the pointer to the data structure to `unsigned long`, store it in `data` field of `struct timer_list` and cast the argument of the timer function back to the pointer to your data structure. This seems to be a common practice.

[Linux Driver Development, 3rd. ed.](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) states the following on that matter in chapter 7:

> If you need to pass multiple items in the argument, you can bundle them as a single data structure and pass a pointer cast to unsigned long, a safe practice on all supported architectures and pretty common in memory management (as discussed in Chapter 15).

There are many examples of this in the kernel, see, for instance, [`s_err_report` timer](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext4/super.c?v=3.7#L3754) in ext4 file system module. A pointer to `struct super_block` is passed to the timer function with casts to `unsigned long` and back as described above.

Comment: Instructive answer. After having looked the existing example from the Kernel, something strikes me : there is no surrounding `#ifdef` on the pointer assignment. Thus if the `long` is not _enough_ to safely cast the pointer, it will lead to undefined behaviour later on (at worst) or prevent compilation if -Werror is set (at best). An architecture that does not enforce this size alignment thus cannot have a reliable ext4 support ?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, for each architecture supported by the kernel, `sizeof(unsigned long)` is the same as `sizeof(void *)` for the code running in the kernel mode. The user mode applications is another story, different rules may apply there. There is an interesting comparison of sizes of various data types on a dozen of architectures in chapter 11 of "Linux Driver Development" book I cited earlier.

Comment: One more quote from that chapter 11 stating that explicitly. "Therefore, generic memory addresses in the kernel are usually unsigned long, exploiting the fact that pointers and long integers are always the same size, at least on all the platforms currently supported by Linux."

Comment: BTW, some memory allocation functions widely used in the kernel return the address of the allocated memory block as `unsigned long` rather than as a pointer. [`__get_free_pages()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=__get_free_pages) is one of the examples. It seems, a lot depends on the free conversions between the addresses and the long integers in the kernel although that may seem unusual. In user-space, such practices are of course discouraged.

Comment: Very useful hints. Thank you for having pointed that out ! Too bad I can't upvote more than once

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I'm attempting to compile a driver on an Ubuntu system with a 3.11 x64 kernel and I get a compile warning "cast from pointer to integer of different size" when attempting to cast a pointer to an `unsigned long` in order to put it in the `data` field of the `timer_list` structure.

Comment: @reirab: Hm, on x64, `sizeof(void *)` and `sizeof(unsigned long)` should be equal (both are 8). A wild guess may be, but are you sure you cast the pointer to unsigned long and not to unsigned int?

Comment: @Eugene I had in mind that it was `unsigned long`, but you might be right that it was `unsigned int`. It wasn't actually my code. I was just compiling a 3rd party driver. I wouldn't write code that assumes a pointer will fit in an integer type that it's not defined to be guaranteed to fit in in the first place. :)